# Where can I download the dalvik.system package of Android?

Tags: android, dalvik

There  is `dalvik.system` package is android.jar, but there is no sources of this package in android sdk.
I want to download the android 15 's full sources? where to get it?

Comment: Please accept an answer if it answers your question. I see that you have asked 7 questions, including 6 upon which you received an answer for, but you never accepted even one as an answer to your question. It is the least you can do when someboy takes the trouble to give you an answer.

Answer (score 3):

See http://s.android.com/source/index.html for instructions to download the full android source tree.

In particular, the libcore project, which contains the dalvik.system package, is at https://android.googlesource.com/platform/libcore/

```
git clone https://android.googlesource.com/platform/libcore
```